# Can I use GeoServer 2.1.3 with proxy extension?

Tags: geoserver, proxy

Can i use GeoServer 2.1.3 with proxy extension, provided here: http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GeoServer+Proxy+Extension ? When add it to geoserver and go to "Proxy Admin Page" - it shows error (*HTTP Status 500 -*). If the versions are incompatible - where to find new proxy extension?

**Part of tomcat access log:**

`"GET /geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.proxy.ProxyAdminPage HTTP/1.1" 500 12031`

**Part of tomcat log:**

```
Mar 07, 2012 2:09:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [geoserver] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is     java.lang.VerifyError: class org.geoserver.web.proxy.HostnameProvider overrides final method model.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/apache/wicket/model/IModel;] with root cause
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.geoserver.web.proxy.HostnameProvider overrides final method model.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/apache/wicket/model/IModel;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2823)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1655)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1674)
at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.constructor(DefaultPageFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:53)
at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:138)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:23)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:49)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:394)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
at org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:71)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.filters.ReverseProxyFilter.doFilter(ReverseProxyFilter.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:41)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`
```

Comment: I'm using Geoserver 2.1.3, facing the same problem. However, I found a jar here:
http://repo.opengeo.org/org/geoserver/community/proxy/2.1-SNAPSHOT/ Good luck mapping!

Comment: can u tell how will call this c# handler in open layer java script ? and what changes needed to web.config ?

Comment: @Abid, sorry, can't answer you exactly. This project was done almost a year ago and im not maintaining it now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoServer plugins tend to be closely linked to the version of GeoServer - so for a 2.1.x build of GeoServer  you need to look in http://gridlock.opengeo.org/geoserver/2.1.x/ to find the plugins that will work.

However I don't see a proxy plugin there so you'll probably need to grab the source for the plugin and see if you can build it against trunk.

Comment: Strange..I thought that its a common problem to use the proxy, because application sure can be not on the Geoserver's server. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: usually you put the application in the GeoServer www directory to avoid the problem or run a proxy in apache's cgi-bin

Comment: Im .net developer..So i usually do not work with systems, other than MS ones. Here i was given a virtual image of CentOs with preinstalled geoserver on tomcat+Oracle. I dont want to put anything MY on that server, that's why i want to host my application(probably asp.net one with client using OpenLayers) on IIS, on another server.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by writing my own small proxy class. It must be in the same directory as calling code.

```
 <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="xDomainProxy" %>

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

public class xDomainProxy : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        var remoteUrl = request.QueryString["url"];

        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteUrl);
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        req.Method = request.HttpMethod;
        req.ContentType = request.ContentType;
        req.UserAgent = request.UserAgent;
        //var basicPwd = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("basicPwd");
        //req.Credentials = basicPwd == null ?
        //    CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials :
        //    new NetworkCredential(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, basicPwd);
        req.PreAuthenticate = true;
        req.Headers["Remote-User"] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        foreach (string each in request.Headers)
            if (!WebHeaderCollection.IsRestricted(each) && each != "Remote-User")
                req.Headers.Add(each, request.Headers.Get(each));
        if (request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            var outputStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            CopyStream(request.InputStream, outputStream);
            outputStream.Close();
        }

        HttpWebResponse response;
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
            if (response == null)
            {
                context.Response.Write(we.Message);
                context.Response.End();
                return;
            }
        }

        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
        context.Response.StatusDescription = response.StatusDescription;
        context.Response.ContentType = response.ContentType;
        if (response.Headers.Get("Location") != null)
        {
            var urlSuffix = response.Headers.Get("Location");
            if (urlSuffix.ToLower().StartsWith(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ProxyUrl"].ToLower()))
                urlSuffix = urlSuffix.Substring(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ProxyUrl"].Length);
            context.Response.AddHeader("Location", request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + urlSuffix);
        }
        foreach (string each in response.Headers)
            if (each != "Location" && !WebHeaderCollection.IsRestricted(each))
                context.Response.AddHeader(each, response.Headers.Get(each));

        CopyStream(response.GetResponseStream(), context.Response.OutputStream);
        response.Close();
        context.Response.End();
    }

    static public void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        while (true)
        {
            int read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (read <= 0)
                return;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```